# configure log4j2-spring.xml with java -cp command

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

I am creating a thin jar for my spring boot project with log4j2-spring.xml outside the jar, all the dependent jars are placed in the libs folder and I have tried below commands to map log4j2-spring.xml but with that, I was able to start my application but logs file was not getting created.

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j2-spring.xml -cp "my-service-1.1.jar;libs/*" com.xxx.yyy.MyService -Dspring.config.location=file:application.properties
```

All the files are kept inside the target folder and I have also created logs folder inside the target folder, but no log is being created.
However when I used the below command log file was created and application also started up on windows machine, but when I used the same command on Linux machine it was not working i.e. not able to pick up log4j2-spring.xml

```
java -Dlogging.config=file:log4j2-spring.xml -cp "my-service-1.1.jar;libs/*" com.xxx.yyy.MyService -Dspring.config.location=file:application.properties
```

In Linux machine I have replaced ; with :

```
java -Dlogging.config=file:log4j2-spring.xml -cp "my-service-1.1.jar:libs/*" com.xxx.yyy.MyService -Dspring.config.location=file:application.properties
```

Luckily the log file got created but whenever I tried to hit an API it was no logs was written in the log file. No write is happening in the log file.

Below is the log4j2-spring.xml content

```
<Configuration>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">logs</Property>
        <property name="component" value="myService " />
        <property name="productLine" value="XXX" />
        <property name="category" value="tracelog" />
    </Properties>

    <Appenders> 
        <!--Console-Appender -->
        <Console name="Console-Appender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
               <pattern> %5p [%thread] | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %F | %L | %X{props} %X{props1} | %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>

        <!-- Rolling File Appender -->
        <RollingRandomAccessFile
            name="Rolling-Random-Access-File-Appender"
            fileName="${log-path}/my-service.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/archive/my-service-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log-%i.gz">
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading

1. [Logging in the Cloud](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/cloud.html) - especially the Managing Logging Configuration section.
2. [Log4j Spring Cloud Configuration](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-spring-cloud-config/log4j-spring-cloud-config-client/index.html)
3. [Log4j Spring Cloud Sample Application](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/tree/release-2.x/log4j-spring-cloud-config/log4j-spring-cloud-config-samples/log4j-spring-cloud-config-sample-application)

While these are primarily focused on integrating Log4j with Spring Boot and Spring Cloud Configuration you should be able to extrapolate how to bypass using Spring Cloud Configuration if you don't want to use that. The sample application shows how to configure a Spring Boot application and configure logging so that it can retrieve the logging configuration. But the bootstrap.yml can be configured with multiple configurations such as:

```
logging:
  config: classpath:log4j2.xml
---
spring:
  profiles: dev
logging:
  config: file://${user.dir}/log4j2-dev.xml
```

With this the application will use the embedded log4j2.xml when no profile is specified and will use log4j2-dev.xml when the dev profile is activated.

You should also note the log4j2.component.properties file in the sample application. The configuration in that file will be used the first time logging is configured in your application. It will then be overridden by the configuration specified in bootstrap.yml every time Spring Boot initializes logging.

The point of these changes is to move the definition of the location into your application configuration but to still let the location vary depending on the environment. This frees you from having to add extra stuff to the command line.